# React Native async (firebase) image fetch in ScrollView / FlatList / SectionList

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, react-native, firebase-storage

I have a SectionList with a lot of images that is being fetched from a firebase storage. When scrolling down it rapidly builds up a lot of warnings.

[image]

The WebImage component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Image } from 'react-native'
import firebase from 'firebase'

class WebImage extends Component {
  state = {
    imgsrc: '',
    mounted: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ mounted: true })

    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child(this.props.source)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(url => {
        if (this.state.mounted) {
          this.setState({ imgsrc: url })
        }
      })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({ mounted: false })
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}

export default WebImage
```

As you can see I tried to make it aware of the mounting state, but it haven't worked as expected..

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
  state = {
    imgsrc: '',
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ref = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child(this.props.source)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(url => {
        this.setState({ imgsrc: url })
      })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.ref.cancel()
  }
```

Read [latest on Async React](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data) and changed  my answer from `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount`.

> There is a common misconception that fetching in componentWillMount lets you avoid the first empty rendering state. In practice this was never true because React has always executed render immediately after componentWillMount. If the data is not available by the time componentWillMount fires, the first render will still show a loading state regardless of where you initiate the fetch. This is why moving the fetch to componentDidMount has no perceptible effect in the vast majority of cases.